# How to import the data of a (sklearn) dataset into plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

`Plotly` has already included some sample datasets. If one's happy to use any `px.data` may be used, say:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
features = ["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "petal_width", "petal_length"]

fig = px.scatter_matrix(
    df,
    dimensions=features,
    color="species"
)
fig.update_traces(diagonal_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

But, how can one import a dataset which is not one of the default datasets of `Plotly`? For example, I need to load the iris dataset of sklearn. But the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

def sklearn_to_df(sklearn_dataset):
    df = pd.DataFrame(sklearn_dataset.data, columns=sklearn_dataset.feature_names)
    df['target'] = pd.Series(sklearn_dataset.target)
    return df

df = px.pd(sklearn_to_df(load_iris()))

features = df.columns.values.tolist()

fig = px.scatter_matrix(
    df,
    dimensions=features,
    color="species"
)

fig.update_traces(diagonal_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

throws a `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` error. How can I handle this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `species` in the dataframe :

```
iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)

features = df.columns.values.tolist()

# map target to species class 
target_map = {i: iris.target_names[i] for i in range(0, len(iris.target_names))}

df['species'] = pd.Series(iris.target).map(target_map)

fig = px.scatter_matrix(
    df,
    dimensions=features,
    color="species"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

t says module object is not callable, because your code is calling a module object. A module object is the type of thing you get when you import a module. What you were trying to do is to call a class object within the module object that happens to have the same name as the module that contains it.

Here is a way to logically break down this sort of error:

"module object is not callable. Python is telling me my code trying to call something that cannot be called. What is my code trying to call?"
"The code is trying to call on socket. That should be callable! Is the variable socket is what I think it is?`
I should print out what socket is and check print socket